# Almost unseeable light moving over nightsky. What is it?

Tags: star, light, movement

Sometimes when I look up at the sky at night, I can see something moving. It’s so small that I barely can see it, but I can’t see it when I look directly at it. I need to look beside it to see it. It slowly moves across the sky, but it switches sometimes directions. It sometimes disappears and after a while, it’s back. It’s not a strong light at all so it’s easy to miss.

Comment: Where are you located geographically? Are you in a city, town, or dark countryside? If you're at a high northerly latitude (or high southerly latitude) this could be an aurora, as I've seen auroras that look pretty much like you describe from surburban locations at 45 north latitude.

Comment: Could be a satellite; there are lots of faint ones. Need more details: your location, what time you saw it, where it was in the sky, what direction it moved. See [Heavens Above](https://www.heavens-above.com/AllSats.aspx) for possibilities.

Comment: I’m in a dark countryside

Comment: I’ve seen it mostly little bit past midnight and i think it has moved towards north most of the times I’ve seen it, but it changes directions and sometimes stops. I’m located at a high northerly latitude.

Comment: @Zandra Is this a diffuse light or a point source? I took you to mean a diffuse light, but if you mean a point source then it certainly isn't an aurora.

Comment: If it moves, it isn't an astronomical object. If it changes direction, it isn't a satellite.